# Getting undefined while displaying the JSON response in the table

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am displaying the JSON response in the table but I am getting `undefined`. I am getting one record or more than one record from the database. I am getting the correct output in the alert.
**Controller**

```
if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row){
                $arr_result[] = $row->first_name .', '. $row->last_name .', '. $row->phone .', '.$row->chss_no;  
             }
                echo json_encode($arr_result);
            }
```

Ajax

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        var cust_name = $('#cust_name').val();
        var mobile_no = $('#mobile').val();                             
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + "/Search/get_search_result",
            method: "POST",
            data: {cust_name: cust_name,mobile_no:mobile_no},
            success: function(response) {
                var data = JSON.parse(response);
                var trHTML = '';
                    $.each(data, function (i, o){
                    trHTML += '<tr><td>' + o.first_name +
                             '</td><td>' + o.last_name +
                             '</td><td>' + o.phone +
                             '</td></tr>';
                          });
                  $('.search_record tbody').append(trHTML);
           }
       });

    }
```

**Table**

```
<div class="search_record" >      
   <table id="" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>  
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                    <th>Lastname</th>
                    <th>Mobile</th>
                  </tr>
                 </thead>            
                <tbody> 

                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
```

I am getting the output

In the `alert(response)`

```
[
    "Praveen, , 2121212121, jbhdbdhdb",
    "Praveen, Sharma, 9898981234, 09\/ACDE10",
    "Praveen, Sharma, 9898981234, 09\/ACDE10",
    "Praveen, Sharma, 9898981234, 09\/ACDE10"
]
```

In the table output
[image]

Comment: Is it in string type? Check it in `console.log()` and it should be as array not string.

Comment: Your array is an array of strings, not an array of objects.  There are no keys for that, as you are trying to reference them.  Just look at your json.

Comment: you just have an array of simple strings, not objects. There is no first_name, last_name or phone property anywhere in your array. There isn't even an object which could have such a property - it's very easy to see that from your `response` data. Do you not understand your data, perhaps? Where did you imagine those fields were coming from? They cannot just appear by magic. The best thing is to change your server-side code so it outputs the data in a more structured JSON format.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I am getting the same output which I added in the question after adding console.log()

Comment: You should fix this in `/Search/get_search_result`, otherwise the fix will get ugly.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think you're going down the wrong track - the problem is simple, see mine and Taplar's comments

Comment: Yep... This issue exists in the server side. Not on the client side...

Comment: @ADyson. Yep. Sorry... Gotcha.

Comment: @ADyson, Yes, I updated my code.

Comment: @Adder, Can you explain your last comment?

Comment: @user9437856 I have posted an answer, I assume this is PHP on the server, it looks like it (I amended the tags). Adder means that if you try to fix this in JavaScript you'll end up with more complicated and ugly code because you'll have to split each array string into pieces to find the individual values which is messier than just having a proper object structure to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have an array of simple strings, not objects. There is no first_name, last_name or phone property anywhere in your array. There isn't even an object which could have such a property - it's very easy to see that from your response data.

The best thing is to change your server-side code so it outputs the data in a more structured JSON format:

```
$arr_result = array();

if (count($result) > 0)
{
  foreach ($result as $row)
  {
    $arr_result[] = array(
      "first_name" => $row->first_name,
      "last_name" => $row->last_name,
      "phone" => $row->phone,
      "chss" => $row->chss_no
    );
  }
}

echo json_encode($arr_result);
```

I have also amended the code slightly so it will always output an empty array in JSON format even if there are no results.

Comment: Yes, It's working. It's my fault to not share the whole code. I will not repeat this issue in the future. Thank you very much.. Upvote from my side.

Comment: Can you help me out in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782682/how-to-call-json-from-multiple-nested-if-condition

Answer (score 1):

You should place the `$row`s into the array as they are before encoding them as JSON, as an object or array:

```
$arr_result = array();
if (count($result) > 0) {
    foreach ($result as $row){
        $arr_result[] = $row;  
    }
    echo json_encode($arr_result);
} else {
    echo "[]";
}
```

Comment: this will also work but I would caution that if `$row` contains other fields which should not be made visible, this code will return them to the client in the JSON. We don't know from the code posted whether that's the case or not. In general it's usually more prudent to build an object containing specifically what is required for the use case, even if it takes a few more lines of code to achieve.

Comment: @Adder,Can you help me out with this issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166869/how-to-display-the-secondary-records-in-the-data-table-child-row-with-respective

Comment: @user9437856 Im looking at it but it isn't easy