# How to display the secondary records in the data table child row with respective id?

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter, datatables

I am using CodeIgniter and data table with child row.
What I am doing is I have a master table with a primary member and a secondary member. Primary member can identify using `member_type=1` and secondary member `member_type=2`. Both members are connected with the relation table. I am able to display the records in the data table with the primary member as well as a secondary member.

Now I am using the data table child row plugin(https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html). I have to display the primary member in the list if the user wants to check the secondary member of the specific primary member then should click on plus sign image and they will get the secondary member list.

**So the output will be**

[image]

**Explanation of the code**

Now I am calling two model from the Listdetails_ajax(). First for the primary records(`getTotalList_of_primary();`) and second for the secondary records(`getTotalList_of_secondary()`). In the first model, I get the primary details with id and that id I am passing to the second model to get the secondary member record related to the id.

Issue is,

1) I am getting the all the records in the data table(I need only primary records)

2) How do I assign the child value in the data table?

Would you help me out with this issue?
**Controller**

```
public function Listdetails_ajax(){  
   $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
$start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
$length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
$books = $this->Search_model->getTotalList_of_primary();

$data['draw'] = 1;
$data['recordsTotal'] = count($books);
$data['recordsFiltered'] = count($books);
foreach ($books as $key => $row) 
{
    //print_r($row->customer_id);
    $arr_result = array(
                "member_id" => base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->member_id)),
                "profile_pic" => $row->profile_pic,
                "name" => $row->first_name.' ' .$row->last_name,
                "phone" => $row->phone,
                "chss_no" => $row->chss_no,
                "emp_id" => $row->emp_id,
                "address" => $row->address
                // "member_type" => $row->member_type
    );
     $data['data'][] = $arr_result;
     $books_of_secondary = $this->Search_model->getTotalList_of_secondary($row->customer_id);
     print_r($arr_result);
     foreach ($books_of_secondary as $key => $row) 
        {
            //print_r($row->customer_id);
            $arr_result2 = array(
                        "s_member_id" => base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->member_id)),
                        "s_profile_pic" => $row->profile_pic,
                        "s_name" => $row->first_name.' ' .$row->last_name,
                        "s_phone" => $row->phone,
                        "s_chss_no" => $row->chss_no,
                        "s_emp_id" => $row->emp_id,
                        "s_address" => $row->address
            );


            $data['data'][] = $arr_result2;
              print_r($arr_result2);
        }
  }
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
}
```

**Model**

```
public function getTotalList_of_primary(){
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('members');
      $this->db->where('member_type',1);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $res   = $query->result();        
     return $res;
}
public function getTotalList_of_secondary($id){
      $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('members'); 
      $this->db->join('relation_member', 'relation_member.secondary_member_id = members.member_id'); 
      $this->db->where('relation_member.primary_customer_id',$id);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      $res   = $query->result();
      return $res;
}
```

**Datatable**

```
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.s_name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Mobile number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.s_phone+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+     
    '</table>';
}

$(document).ready(function() {
            var oTable =$('#all_list').DataTable( {
                "processing": true,
                // "serverSide": true,
                "pageLength": 10,
                "ajax": {
                    "url": baseUrl+ "/index.php/Search/Listdetails_ajax",
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "columns": [
                   {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
                    },
                { "data": "member_id","className": "display_none"},
                { "data": "profile_pic","className":"img_list_pic",
                "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<img src='+baseUrl+'/uploads/images/'+data+' class="search_pic">';
                }
                 },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "phone" },
                { "data": "chss_no" },
                { "data": "emp_id" },
                { "data": "address" },
            ],


            } );
            // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
     // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#all_list tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = oTable.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');

            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]', tr.next('tr')).tooltip();
        }
    } );

} );
```

**Json**

```
Array
(
    [member_id] => M2EwYzhmNzBjYTYzMTdiMzFiZDFjNGIwY2Y1NmYwNmQ3ZWY0MGEzNTg5OTY2YjBkNWUwZjc3MWY4NWJiZTdmMGM3Y2Y4YTdhZGI4MTM1MTMyMDVmMDQ1NjRkZTVmMmViZjYzMjcxZGVlODhmNzg1OGMzM2M1ZWI0MjUwYjQ5YzVOUDZSRlZKcFhaNWZ0eTg3NVlBT09HcFhwcW5XSGlIaWpYelJpOTduNzI0PQ==
    [profile_pic] => 5b1b88a7cd85a1528531111090618.png
    [name] => alpha bita
    [mobileno] => 9898981234
    [emp_id] => EMP_2018_03
    [address] => Navi Mumbai
)
Array
(
    [s_member_id] => ZWFlMjQwNGEwMGQ2YWVjMzlkZGRkN2Y1ZTQ1ODQ1NDc0N2M5ZDRiZDY3NDkyZDQ2YjNkN2UxZjI4ZTFhY2Y1Y2U1NWI2N2RlMDEyY2M5NDE3NDc2NWNiZmU4MzFjNWYwYzc2OWQxNjIzZDJiM2QwMzg0ODU2OWNjNDY5OWI4MWM0Yjl0YUgzOUVKaGNka2ZuTEp4Tk1EZitraTEyd2NtLzliNk8wSlpQU0FJPQ==
    [s_profile_pic] => 
    [s_name] => Anil 
    [s_phone] => 2121212121
    [s_emp_id] => 
    [s_address] => Navi Mumbai
)
Array
(
    [member_id] => ZDVkYTFiMGM0MGRhNzBjMTg1N2VhMDMyYjU0NDQyMDFlNjMyNDNjNGFhZjg0ODM4YTRhNWJiZjBlODkyZGZkYzk5MGFmN2JjZmFmODM0ZTQ3NzA3NTkwZWFlNGIwYzU2MzBmZGQ0NTZlOTkyMWJiNDc2OTdmN2EyZjJkOGM0NDZDNTlRRVFmK1hoMUNZRlM3R0dFMCtvaGZMclplNWxIYk1DOG0vVklwMjBBPQ==
    [profile_pic] => 5b1b8c15eefe31528531989090618.jpg
    [name] => Ajay Waghmare
    [phone] => 8989855451
    [chss_no] => chss/ajay/2018
    [emp_id] => emp_2018_45
    [address] => Andheri Mumbai
)
Array
(
    [s_member_id] => ZTk1NWYwNWVlMmE3ZTUwMjExMDk3NzlmNTE0YmQ5ZGYzNzkyOTU3M2ZjOGE3YWUyZjg0N2I3ODZhMzhmNWNmNTQ2ZTg1MTM4OGMxNzk4MjFmZWYzMzA3YzViODE5YWNjZmIzNDBlYzJlZTUwYzBhYmRjN2RhZmJmMzk5NjAxOTR1SmJyYngwbE04N0wwTVEyK280V0RhVWlKang4VzBlSExyK0VtQTB4eHlNPQ==
    [s_profile_pic] => 5b1b8fae049341528532910090618.jpg
    [s_name] => Rohit Suman
    [s_phone] => 7885458454
    [s_chss_no] => roh/sum/2018/09
    [s_emp_id] => 
    [s_address] => Andheri Mumbai
)
Array
(
    [s_member_id] => MzVlOGFhM2MwN2RkMzNmYzdiMjhiMzdiNDVhOGMzMTVjZjhlOTFlNzg4ODAxNjFiM2JhZTExZDUxNzg2NDU3MDBmODllZmJlZTcxMThlOWFiODQ4YjAwMThmZGRmNDIxOTU0NWZmYzEwZTg5YzQzOWM3MDBhNGVlM2ZjMDQ5OTFjV3FuZGdsbXJtK3A1YUhFaEI1dTBSWDN5RkhKVVBEbFpJTE95eDdNb3Q0PQ==
    [s_profile_pic] => 5b1b9052d56bd1528533074090618.jpg
    [s_name] => Pankaj 
    [s_phone] => 8989989898
    [s_chss_no] => p/2018/09/05
    [s_emp_id] => 
    [s_address] => Andheri Mumbai
)
```

Comment: Can you give an example how you want `echo json_encode($data);` to look?

Comment: @Adder, I updated my whole code. I am getting the JSON response in network tab. but how do I display in the data table

Comment: Maybe add a flag field `isSecondary` to ` $arr_result` and ` $arr_result2` indicating whether the row is for a primary or secondary result.

Comment: @Adder, I have master table. I have to display the primary member with secondary member list. so I tried two model in the Listdetails_ajax(). first one is getting the all the primary member and sending the id in the seconday member model. Both JSON data i am sending in the view page

Comment: Or do you have any other easy idea to solve this issue? Please

Comment: Yes, I added "isSecondary" =>$row->member_type and I am getting the 1 for primary and 2 is for secondary. what next I have to do?

Comment: Did you try following the example at your link https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html? You would have to change the data structure so that the `$arr_result` contains a field which has the secondaries in it. Forget about the `isSecondary`for the time being.

Comment: @Adder, Yes, I tried that, I added in the question as well

Comment: Another idea is to use jQuery to hide all secondary rows, then show on click the secondary rows folllowing a primary row. For this the `isSecondary` field is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the first idea, using a details popup, the controller would look like this:

```
public function Listdetails_ajax(){  
   $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    $books = $this->Search_model->getTotalList_of_primary();

    $data['draw'] = 1;
    $data['recordsTotal'] = count($books);
    $data['recordsFiltered'] = count($books);
    foreach ($books as $key => $row) 
    {
        //print_r($row->customer_id);
        $arr_result = array(
                    "member_id" => base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->member_id)),
                    "profile_pic" => $row->profile_pic,
                    "name" => $row->first_name.' ' .$row->last_name,
                    "phone" => $row->phone,
                    "chss_no" => $row->chss_no,
                    "emp_id" => $row->emp_id,
                    "address" => $row->address
                    // "member_type" => $row->member_type
        );

         $array_secondary = array();
         $books_of_secondary = $this->Search_model->getTotalList_of_secondary($row->customer_id);
         foreach ($books_of_secondary as $key => $row) 
            {
                //print_r($row->customer_id);
                $arr_result2 = array(
                            "s_member_id" => base64_encode($this->encryption->encrypt($row->member_id)),
                            "s_profile_pic" => $row->profile_pic,
                            "s_name" => $row->first_name.' ' .$row->last_name,
                            "s_phone" => $row->phone,
                            "s_chss_no" => $row->chss_no,
                            "s_emp_id" => $row->emp_id,
                            "s_address" => $row->address
                );


                $array_secondary[] = $arr_result2;
            }
         $arr_result['secondary'] =  $array_secondary;  
         $data['data'][] = $arr_result;
      }
    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
}
```

And then in the format function you would access the `secondary` field to get an array of secondaries. Maybe like this:

```
function format(d) {
    // d is the original data object for the row var val;
    if(d.secondary.length == 0) {
        return "There are no secondary members";
    }

    var display = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'; 
    for (val of d.secondary) { 
        display += '<tr>' + '<td>Full name:</td>' + '<td>' + val.s_name + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '<tr>' + '<td>Mobile number:</td>' + '<td>' + val.s_phone + '</td>' + '</tr>';
    }
    display += '</table>';
    return display;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, how do I access the secondary data?

Comment: I imagine you would access it with `d.secondary`. Check whether it is an array by `console.dir(d.secondary);`

Comment: I tried   '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.s_name+'</td>'+ but it's give me undefined

Comment: Yes I understand that. You need to loop over `d.secondary` and then add a row to a table for each element in it, which will have a `s_name` field.

Comment: Yes, I am getting the array value in console

Comment: Yes, I tried, your logic and code are working for me but I am getting the little bit issue. I added "for condition" in format. It's displaying only 1 secondary member.  I have also more than one secondary member of some primary id.

Comment: I tried function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
var val;
for (val of d.secondary) {
    //console.log(val);
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+val.s_name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Mobile number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+val.s_phone+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+     
    '</table>';
    }
}

Comment: Oh my god! you are the luckiest man for me in the world now. My issue got resolved perfectly. many many thanks. I am facing this issue from last 12-15days and you solved it within 15 min.  Thank you @Adder.

Comment: I just need to know if there is no secondary member than how to display the Message " There are no secondary member"

Comment: Edited my answer. It is nice to work together with someone who is able to code with a little hinting.

Comment: Many many Thanks, @Adder, It's working for me perfectly. upvote from my side.

Comment: @Adder, Can you help me out with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56868489/message-uninitialized-string-offset-0-while-inserting-dynamic-input-field-data